# What value is returned when calling Firebase ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am working on a android project that connected to firebase real time db. 
Anyway, I am putting timeStamp somewhere.

```
...
.... 
map2.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP); 
message_root.updateChildren(map2);
```

Then I am calling this data succesfully

```
    ...
    ...
    chat_time = (Long)((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int a = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int b = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int c = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

No problem in implementation. The problem is that I  could not understand this value is different in smartphone and emulator.
For same value in emulator it shows(for example) 17:16, in smartphone 20:16 altough the value is same in realtime database when I look from firebase console.
Finally, what is the real value? Does this value change according to country? But my smartphone and emulator are in the same country. I am confused.

Comment: I noticed that my simulator time shows 3 hours before. Then everything seems nice but how is this happening? Eventually, it stores ONE value in database

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Firebase Reference Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP), the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is:

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time
>   since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database
>   servers.

When I read your question, I decided to try it on the emulator. And it gave me the same value for both the emulator and real device: the current time in my country (GMT+2).

I also tried changing my device's time. But still, the value posted to the database is the current time.
Then I tried changing the time zone in the Firebase Console Project Configuration. But the value is still the same.

If you say that the value posted is the same, but you're getting different values, maybe you should tell us how are you showing this value?

Comment: Hmm, I solved my problem. In fact it shows true time because my emulator clock 3 hours back from my real device. Then no problem, it shows according to device time. Good, I like it.